# GXT TextField shows as (null handle), rendered = false, getValue() = null, even though HTML shows the widget is rendered and has value

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

I have a form with several GXT `SimpleComboBox` and `TextField` widgets.  They are layed out in an elaborate form, with validators, default values, conditional enabling/disabling, etc.  The problem is that one particular `TextField.getValue()` is returning `null`, and failing form submission due to this validation error.  The entered value is valid, in accordance with the regex used for the field's validator (proven working for other fields, where the same regex is used to set validators on those fields).  Debugging shows that the field is `(null handle)`, instead of HTML that is shown for other `TextField`s.  Flag `rendered` is `false`.  Strangely, the field with that id is indeed rendered in the browser and contains a value.  I'm using IE8, gxt 3.0.1 rc2.  Method `getRawValue()` is returning empty.  I've recompiled the entire project, and still experiecing this.  There appears to be a disconnect between what is rendered and the Eclipse (keplar) debugger. I'm running in development mode.

Comment: Please can you share some piece of code relevant to this issue?

Comment: I would if I could.  I'm hoping someone is previously aware of this issue.